# Saving Changes using breeze without Entity Framework

Tags: breeze

I am  beginner in breeze, I want to integrate it into an ASP.net  MVC4  project .

I have the same problem in [Saving Data Using Breeze.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183341/saving-data-using-breeze-js)
  but this post did not answer the problem and I hope we can do it this time

The problem is that I don’t have to use Entity Framework and I don’t know how to replace ContextProvider in SaveChanges method in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges (JObject saveBundle) {

return ContextProvider.SaveChanges (saveBundle);
}
```

I also tried to customize ressourceName by using SaveOptions:

```
var option = new breeze.SaveOptions ({resourceName 'MyContoller'});

              entityManager.saveChanges (null, optional)
                       . then (
             alert ("ok");


           )
                      . fail (function (e) {

                       alert (e);
                     });
```

When I run it no problem starts but the controller does not receive data!

So my question is:
 How can I save changes with breeze without using EntityFramework?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I redefined savaChanges method  to read the json data and assign it to my object, but I'm not sure that  it is the right way:

This is my SaveChanges method

```
[HttpPost]
        public void SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            JToken jMyObject = saveBundle["entities"];
            MyClass myObject= new MyClass ();
            string state=(string) jMyObject [0]["entityAspect"]["entityState"];
            if (state == "Added")
            {
               myObject.name =
(string) jMyObject [0]["name"];
                CreateEntity(myObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the NoDb sample in the Breeze zip?

Comment: Yes I saw the NoDB sample , I tried to do the same but it does not work for me  I don’t know why!!
Knowing that I use  SQL server 2005

Comment: Sorry with more info, its difficult to know what is happening. We do offer a Breeze support package on the Breeze website. This would support having a Breeze engineer actually take a look at your aoplication.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I will review my application … there is also a new version of breeze (1.4.0) I'll try to integrate it, if the problem persists I will post the problem with more information